# Get object only with interface fields in the JSON format

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
 public class Group: IGroupe{

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And have an interface:

```
public interface IGroupe
{
    int GroupId { get; set; }
    string GroupeName { get; set; }
}
```

I want creat and return object `groupe` in JSON format. 
How can I get object with only interface fields without `Students` ?

```
IGroupe groupe=new Group();
return Ok(groupe);
```

Dont work, we have all fields when return object in JSON format.

`[JsonIngore]` . does not fit, because I have other method that should return full object.

Comment: You ask about json format, but your question does not contain any code handling json, which makes it unclear. Please [edit] your question to explain if you want the `Students` to not be serialized to json or to not be deserialized from json, as well as the code you currently have to serialize\deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return the structure of your `IGroupe` interface, you could create an anonymous object - do sth like:

```
IGroupe groupe = new Group();
return Ok(new {GroupId = groupe.GroupId, GroupeName = groupe.GroupName});
```